# Can you prevent the drag & drop function in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a 'Task spreadsheet' in my company, where employees fill in certain Google spreadsheet cells the time they finished a task. This worked very well for years, but lately, more and more young millennials come, who didn't grow up with computers, but tablets/smartphones, resulting in a cluttered spreadsheet because cells get dragged and dropped everywhere. I tried to protect cells, but that prevent others to enter data.

Is there a way to disable the drag and drop function in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't such option to disable drag&drop future in Google Sheets. Your option remains to protect ranges which shouldn't be filled by data. Also, you could set up multiple slave sheets/spreadsheets (which will act like some sort of template) and have 1 master sheet/spreadsheet which will hunt down required data.

Comment: mmmm slave sheets, never heard of that, but I think I understand what you mean and sounds like a great idea

Comment: @Richard https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers